# Can a property $P$ for real numbers be defined as eventually true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Considering a property of natural numbers $P(n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N} $, $P(n)$  is said to be **eventually** true if $\exists n^{*} \in  \mathbb{N} \mid P(n)$ is true $\forall n>n^{*}$.

For example

$P(n):$ "$n$ is even" is not **eventually** true

$P(n): n-3\geq 0$ is **eventually** true

If I consider a funcion $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, can properties (defined in this case for real numbers) be defined as  **eventually** true ?

For istance can I say that a function in  **eventually** bounded?

The fact is that the definition of a **eventually** property is given for  natural numbers, and I would like to know if the same is said in the case of real numbers or if it does not make sense.

Thanks for your help

Comment: And don’t forget that in many languages, *eventually* doesn’t mean what it means in English: most often, it means “contingently”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of some property holding eventually is not new and is actually very common in mathematics, though often not called so. For example, recall the definition of convergence of sequence of real numbers. It can be equivalently stated as:

> Sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $l$ if for any $\varepsilon$ *eventually* we have $x_n\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$.

This notion of "eventuality" is often hidden behind the words "property holds *for all sufficiently large $n$*". This notion makes perfect sense both in natural numbers and real numbers.